# Why can I use the asset pipeline but require_tree . doesn't work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, asset-pipeline

I upgraded my app (which runs on heroku) to use the asset pipeline a while ago.

I moved all the files into app/assets, listed each on in app/assets/javascript/application.js and deleted public.

When I push to heroku the assets are compiled and the site works well.

However if I try to use require_tree instead of listing the files, it doesn't works either locally or on Heroku.  I do get an application.js file but it just seems to be filled with the jquery source code and none of my code and none of my js is working anywhere.

I've also tried forcing jquery to load first in case of dependency using:

```
$ cat application.js 
// Place your application-specific JavaScript functions and classes here
// This file is automatically included by javascript_include_tag :defaults
//
//= require jquery-1.7.2.min.js
//= require jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js
//= require_tree .
```

but it didn't help.

If I revert to using:

```
$ cat application.js 
// Place your application-specific JavaScript functions and classes here
// This file is automatically included by javascript_include_tag :defaults
//
//= require_self
//= require jquery-1.7.2.min
//= require jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min
//= require default_on_first_input_field
//= require row_shading
//= require long_or_short_details
//= require sortable_hook
//= require date-picker
//= require rails
```

and push that to production, everything works fine and the various js is available.

In either case the js application page is included in `app/views/layouts/application.html.haml` with

```
= javascript_include_tag "application"
```

I get the same problem locally with require_tree.  In this case, my javascript snippets don't work, even though I have

```
 <script src="/assets/jquery-1.7.2.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/date-picker.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/default_on_first_input_field.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/long_or_short_details.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/rails.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/row_shading.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/sortable_hook.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

in the HTML head

As the application was originally rails 2.3.8 and has gone thru many upgrades is there anything that might cause this behavior?

I've looked in the javascript console but no errors there that would seem to explain it.

In the page itself I end up with:

```
  <script src="/assets/jquery-1.7.2.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/date-picker.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/default_on_first_input_field.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/long_or_short_details.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/rails.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/row_shading.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/sortable_hook.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Did you fix that? Cause it's really weird, I'm curious

Answer (score 1):

Have you try this?

```
//= require jquery-1.7.2.min.js
//= require jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js
//= require_tree .
//= require_self
```

Seems in your post that you removed `require_self`

Comment: My mistake.  I added it back.  The above didnt work.